# Multiple entries for a specific content type in MODx?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I'm new to MODx and am just looking for the direction to go. Basically I'm looking for a way to manage many entires of the same type of content, for example, I have a page that shows all client reviews, I imagine theres a way for a site admin to add an individual review to the reviews page?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very very easy, create your 'reviews' as a container resource, create your reviews as child resources [of 'reviews'] ~ hide them from your menus, then use the getResources extra to pull the content out of the child resources into a custom chunk. You can even use template variables or nested folders to further organize them or even 'rate' them.

Comment: This is definitely the most simple approach but also a bit hackish because of using resources for what they are not really there and clutters up the resource tree. Also, if you want to do it cleanly (and maybe someone who didn't set it up this way has to use it), you would have to add some means to guarantee that these resources always stay hidden, so they don't accidentally show up in some menu etc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use container resources and use getResources to aggregate and list them as you need them. Basically what Sean says.

Alternatively you can also (if you're a dev or have the budget to hire one) build a [Custom Resource Class](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Custom+Resource+Classes), which is a new feature in MODX Revolution 2.2+. This would allow you to customize the management interface and pretty much any underlying process to make a truly  custom tailored solution. It may be overkill for most, but it could improve the management experience if done right. [There's a tutorial for it here](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Creating+a+Resource+Class).

Answer (score 0):

Besides creating the reviews as normal child resources or Custom Resource Classes, you might also have a look at the extra [MIGX](http://modx.com/extras/package/migx).

It provides you with a TV that makes it very easy to manage a list of an indefinite amount of entries. You can arbitrarily sort these entries, have entries consist of multiple different TVs (even on distinct tabs), you can do it quickly and it keeps your resource tree clean.

To get you started, have a look at the [documentation](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/addon/MIGX) or read Mark Hamstra's [tutorial](http://www.markhamstra.com/modx-blog/2012/04/managing-galleries-with-migx/) on building an Image Gallery with MIGX.